# How to add settings in my ios application?

Tags: ios, settings

In my application , I need to add settings (turn off advertising , video play , notification and more ). How to control my entire application according to this settings?
[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use  settings bundle https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html

Comment: i want to build settings in side my application

Comment: use settings bundle for this

Answer (score 2):

**Adding Settings inside application:**

You can use custom `UITableView` and `NSUserDefaults` for creating a custom settings page like that.

Or you can use a third-party control called [InAppSettingsKit](http://www.inappsettingskit.com/)

---

**Adding Settings in Settings application:**

You need to use Settings.bundle for adding the settings to settings application.
Check [Implementing an iOS Settings Bundle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html) for more details.